# How do I retrieve the object details in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, firebase, ionic-framework

I have tried to search for a solution to my problem but it seems my code should work. I have retrieved data from firebase and want to display it in my view.
The data object is shown in the developer console as being there when I am in the view in question.

My view:

```
  <ion-view cache-view="false" ng-controller="PostCtrl">
   <ion-nav-title>{{ viewname }}</ion-nav-title>
     <ion-content class="has-header contentpane">

        <div class="titlepane">
            <h4 class="posttitle">
                {{item.title}}
            </h4>
            <p class="categorytitle">
                {{item.category}}
            </p>
        </div>

  </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

The controller:

```
firebaseApp.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, firebaseApi, $stateParams) {
'use strict';

// Create a name for the view to show as the title
$scope.viewname = 'Svampe';

// The stateParams is defined in the Services.js and defined in the scope here.
$scope.id = $stateParams.id;

// API call to the firebase for a specific post
firebaseApi.getSingle($scope.id).then(function (succ) {
  $scope.item = succ;
  console.log("Items", $scope.item);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err);
});

});
```

Do you have any idea why the data is not showing in the view? I can see the object is retrieved successfully but it's not showing.

Comment: Can you show me  **$scope.item** object.

Comment: {
  "data": {
    "category": "Data Warehousing",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum text about any subject. Description.",
    "id": 1,
    "imgpath": "img/database.png",
    "title": "Data Warehousing"
  },
  "status": 200,
  "config": {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "https://database.firebaseio.com/1.json",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    }
  },
  "statusText": "OK"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
{{item.data.title}}

{{item.data.category}}
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/B9RsQ/40/